# PHP, invalid SQL request

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

```
  $query = 'SELECT name FROM users';
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
```

works well. Now I change my code just a bit

```
  $query = 'SELECT RIGHT(name, 2) FROM users';
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);  // returns false
  $stmt->execute();  // throws an error
```

Does not work. `var_dump($db->errorInfo())` outputs this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'HY000' (length=5)
  1 => int 17
  2 => string 'near "(": syntax error' (length=22)
```

What's the problem? `name` is a `varchar` string and it is longer than 2 symbols and never `null`.

Comment: is there any field with null value in name column?

Comment: What does the error information tell you? For `mysqli` check `$db->error;`, for PDO check `$db->errorInfo();`

Comment: just updated info

Comment: The way that error message is phrased, it sounds like you're using SQLite (MySQL would be more verbose). SQLite doesn't have a `RIGHT()` function, you should be able to use `SUBSTR(name, -2)` to get the same result.

Comment: rickdenhaan, you're so right! Thank you